# How are constants/functions named after their discoverer?

Tags: journals, mathematical-writing

In general, when a paper references an object discovered/defined in another paper by author **X**, it goes something along the lines of:

"*Let $\tau$ be the constant defined by **X** in 1999* [1]$\ldots$",

or

"*Let $f_{\mu}$ denote the function that generalizes the case $\ldots$ (**X**, [1])*".

At what point does the literature start talking about "**X**'s constant" or "The **X** function"?

Who/what determines that an object discovered by somebody *deserves* to take his name?

Comment: It starts this way when an author decides to do so... some authors make efforts to find an intuitive and convenient terminology when introducing something, other don't and sometimes paradoxically get rewarded by having their name attached

Comment: A ludicrous example I have in mind is "Grothendieck group". Grothendieck introduced a number of incredibly subtle concepts, notably in algebraic geometry, generally with an adequate terminology which is generally duly used. But also at some point he used (without claiming credit!) a somewhat much older concept, basically the same as the one to pass from natural to relative numbers... this is a simple construction to pass from an abelian semigroup to an abelian group, which is now often referred as "Grothendieck group".

Comment: Here is a list of [named constants](http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/constants/MathConstants.html#named) --- as far as I could tell, none of these was named by the individual themselves.

Comment: I know an author $x$ who defined (in a joint paper with two colleagues $y,z$) an $x$-pair.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Isn't that a bit pretentious? I thought such naming was "awarded" by other authors in related papers. Or was it adequate to call it an $x$-pair in the given context?

Comment: @Pickle It *looks* pretentious, but it might not actually be. It's at least possible that the terminology "$x$-pair", though first published in the $xyz$ paper, had been used  informally earlier by others (in discussions, in lectures, etc.) and had become reasonably well established in the relevant community.

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to remind people about [Stigler's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy).

Comment: @Pickle : I know nothing about the $x$-pair case, but I can say that William Tutte persisted for some time in using the term "dichromate" for what everyone else called the Tutte polynomial. It was confusing to me, and I'm sure many others, when reading the literature about this polynomial for the first time.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671534/mathematicians-names-in-structures/671573.

Comment: @YCor I am guilty of using the 'Grothendieck group' terminology for just that construction many times on this site; do you have a suggestion for something better?

Comment: @AlecRhea I'd say "group of differences" or "groups of fractions", depending on whether you use additive or multiplicative notation. (But I wouldn't say you should fell guilty to say Grothendieck group, it's well-established.)

Comment: In topology, the term 'group completion' is also frequently used, both for the concept of a 'Grothendieck group' itself and even more often for the topological or $\infty$-categorical analogue.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is determined by informal consensus of researchers in an area. Anyone can propose a name for a mathematical object, just by using this name in a paper. Then the proposed name either sticks to the object or not. This depends on the opinions of other people working in the area. Eventually the name of the object becomes established.
Sometimes several names for the same object become established, and all of them popular.

For example Fatou set is the same as the set of normality. The name Fatou set
was proposed in two influential surveys in 1980s, and many people in the area use it.

The name does not have to be the name of the discoverer of the object.
For example, Drinfeld introduced an object which he named Yangian,
in honor of Chen-Ning Yang.
M. Lyubich and I gave the name "Baker's domain" to an object that we defined. 
Unlike some other "personal names" we proposed in the same paper, this one is used by everyone who writes on the subject. Arnold once stated a principle that
"If the thing is named after someone, this indicates that the person had nothing to do with the thing". M. Berry remarked that "Arnold Principle applies to itself".

Sometimes a multitude of names reflects a priority dispute or nationalistic feelings (Young diagram vs Ferrers diagram, Schwarz inequality vs Cauchy or
Bouniakowski etc.) The name Casorati–Sokhotski–Weierstrass theorem reflects
some priority research, but the theorem in question was earlier stated by Briot and Bouquet. Same happened with "Gauss-Manin connection" which was in fact discovered by Legendre.

Sometimes the accepted name is changed ($\pi$ used to be "Archimedes number" and
$e$ used to be "Euler's number").
A funny story happened with "Koebe constant". It turned out that it is equal to $1/4$, so one mathematician wrote "Now it cannot be called Koebe constant anymore,
because it turns out that it already has a name, namely $1/4$").

Sometimes a name is based on a mistake. For example Abel's equation
is the accepted name for $f(x+1)=g(f(x))$. It is based on a manuscript of Abel, but the manuscript itself turns out to be just Abel's personal notes on
the work of Napier, where the equation was introduced.

People usually do not give their own names to mathematical objects. However,
in his influential book on functional analysis, Banach introduces 
"spaces of type H", "spaces of type F" and "spaces of type "B". As his "spaces of type H and F" are nothing but Hilbert and Frechet spaces, people probably understood the hint:-)

G. Julia intensively lobbied (not publicly, in private correspondence, which is now published) that the "irregular set" be called Julia set. He succeeded.

Remark. I just found the paper, arXix:1204.4716v1 (Bernard Ycart, A case of mathematical eponimy: the Vandermonde determinant), which shows that there is a whole research area related to this question: it is called "mathematical eponimy". The paper cites several other publications on this subject.

Comment: $\pi$ is (or was) sometimes called the "Ludolphine number" ("Ludolphsche Zahl" in German), after Ludolph van Ceulen, who computed 35 digits of $\pi$.

Comment: No I want to use the term Koebe constant for 1/4 for now on.

Comment: Great answer Alexandre. Just want to point out that Young diagrams and Ferrers diagrams ARE slightly different in that they have different orientations. On a personal note, the one time I witnessed a mathematician referring to himself in the sense of this question, was in a talk by Anosov, where he mentioned Anosov maps. It was clear to everyone that he could have not done differently :)  Oh! and do you have a reference for Julia's effort?

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez : It's news to me that Young diagrams and Ferrers diagrams have different orientations. I've seen different orientations for both. The difference, in my experience, is whether you draw a polyomino or a bunch of dots.

Comment: "e used to be "Euler's number"". Is it not still called Eulers number?

Comment: @Tilefish, calling it "Euler's number" does run the risk of confusion with the Euler numbers, or the Eulerian numbers, or the Euler-Macheroni constant... he was that prolific after all.

Comment: @TilefishPoele I think the point is that it's almost always just called "e". But I agree that people use phrases such as "Euler's number" or "the base of natural logarithms" if they need to convey the message "Here, we're using $e$ to denote blah, not $2.718...$."

Comment: From Littlewood's Miscellany - A precisian professor had the habit of saying : '... quartic polynomial $ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$, where $e$ need not be the base of the natural logarithms'.

Comment: @Rodrigo A. Perez: The reference for Julia is the book of M. Audin, Fatou, Julia, Montel..., Springer 2011, where she cites a lot of correspondence.

Comment: @Tilefish Poele: when they say "Euler's constant",  I usually think of the misterious constant which is denoted by $\gamma$.

Comment: Similar to the Koebe constant, Legendre's constant equals 1.

Comment: Here's the wikipedia page for Legendre's constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant

Comment: @Rodrigo A. Pérez: Anosov himself called them У-diffeomorphisms, where У is the first letter of the Russian word условие, which means simply "condition". This was used for some time in the Russian literature, but of course this sounds awkward when translated into English. So all foreign authors called this Anosov diffeomorphisms, and Russians had no choice but to follow.