# Non-integrability of Abel's equation

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations

I frequently encounter in the literature the statement that  Abel's equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x+y^3$$
is not integrable. This is always stated without reference. My questions are

a) What is the precise statement? (I suppose it should be that there is no non-constant meromorphic function (first integral) $F(x,y)$ on $C^2$ which is constant on each solution $y(x)$).

b) Where is this proved?

When I search in the reference books or internet, they list many known cases of integrability of Abel's equations, but no one addresses proofs of non-integrability.

Comment: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Abel_differential_equation gives as a reference the book:  E. Kamke, "Differentialgleichungen: Lösungen und Lösungsmethoden", 1. Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen, Chelsea, reprint (1971)

Comment: I looked into Kamke before asking. It only lists known cases of integrability.

Comment: Abel differential equations admitting a certain first integral, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 370 (2010) 187–199 (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X10003483/pdf) has references to old work on the topic, IMHO.

Comment: @Dima Pesechnik: Which work in the reference list contains a proof of NON-integrability? A brief inspection only reveals "classification of Abel equations having a first integral of particular type".

Comment: actually, looking at cited there https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0001037 tempts me to say that no proof of non-integrability is known. By the way, the latter refers to the original work by Abel on  solvable cases of his equation, perhaps he said something on your case too?

Comment: @Tom Copeland: I am not sure whom you address in your comment, and what is the relation of this question to iteration.

Comment: @Tom Copeland: "Abel's differential equation" and "Abel's functional equation" do not seem to be related. In fact, the second name is a result of mistake: Abel probably has nothing to do with it. See, for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285627/how-are-constants-functions-named-after-their-discoverer/285644#285644

Comment: @Tom Copeland. I do have papers which deal with "Abel functional equaiton", indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Maple's [help on Abel equations](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FAbel) as well as the [text describing this part of Maple ODE code](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0001037)  suggests that indeed no proofs of unsolvability of this (and other(?)) Abel equation are known. To quote:

```
The most general method available at the moment to solve Abel ODEs
 seems to be the method of "Abel's invariant", described in E. Kamke, p. 26, as sub-method (g) due to M. Chini. The invariant of an Abel equation with f2=0 is the following quantity:
>   
Abel_invariant := -1/27/f3(x)^4*(-diff(f0(x),x)*f3(x)+f0(x)*diff(f3(x),x)+
3*f0(x)*f3(x)*f1(x))^3/f0(x)^5
```

We have $f_3=1$, $f_0=x$, so the latter quantity depends on $x$, the case for which this "most general" method does not work.

Comment: I hoped that some MO participants may know more on the subject than Kamke or Maple do.

Answer (score 0):

The paper by Primitivo B. Acosta-Humánez, J. Tomás Lázaro, Juan J. Morales-Ruiz and Chara Pantazi *Differential Galois theory and non-integrability of plane polynomial vector fields*, J. Differential Equations **264** (2018) 7183- 7212 https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2018.02.016 contains both:

a) a definition of integrability (which appears to match your conjectured meaning of the term); and
b) a general theorem for non-integrability for planar polynomial vector fields.